# Removing a file using remove();

Tags: c++

Trying to remove/delete a file using the function below. Unfortunately, it fails every time.
Had cut many lines of code that seemed unrelated to the question.

```
int main()
{
    Login();
}
```

the function below checks the existence of the file. if exists, it can remove it.

```
void Login()
{
    char name[20], password[20], filepassword[10], ID[10], id1[10];
    cout << "Login-->\nEnter user-ID: ";
    cin >> ID;        
    strcpy(id1, ID);   
    strcat(ID,".txt");   //ID is the name of the file (.txt format).
    ifstream inputfromfile;
    inputfromfile.open(ID);
    if(!inputfromfile)
    {
        cout <<"\nInvalid ID.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
//IF FILE EXISTS, BELOW IT WILL BE EXECUTED
    cout << "Password: "; cin >> password;
    inputfromfile filepassword;
    if (strcmp(password, filepassword) != 0) //if password doesn't match
    {
        cout<< "Wrong Password.\n";
        perror("Password incorrect");
    }
    inputfromfile.close();

    cout <<"\nEnter 5 to remove account.\n";
    int x; cin >> x;
    if (x == 5)
    {
        RemoveAccount(ID);
    }
}
```

remove function. it deletes the file/ID (.txt) that exists in the same folder.

```
void RemoveAccount(char ID[])
{
    if (remove(ID)!=0)
    {
        cout << "failed to delete!";
        perror("account remove failed");
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Successfully deleted!";
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

But if i write `remove("jackson.txt")` instead of `remove(ID)`, it works successfully. jackson.txt exists in the same folder.

Comment: `"jackson.txt"` is an array containing 12 characters. Your `char` array `ID` is declared as containing `10` `char`s. So `remove("jackson.txt")` would never be equivalent to `remove(ID)`.

Comment: Don't use `char` arrays for strings in C++, use `std::string` instead. It will simplify many things for you.

Comment: There are _two_ `remove` functions that I know of. Which one are you using? Since you haven't shown what header files you've included and namespaces you are `using` - it's impossible to say.

Comment: RemoveAccount() ---->if(remove()). not sure what you meant.

Comment: I mean that there are two different `remove` functions in the standard library and both remove files. There are actually three - but the third doesn't remove files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"jackson.txt" fits within an array of 12 chars. `ID` is an array of 10 chars. If you use that filename, you will access outside the bounds of the array and behaviour of the program is undefined.

Conclusion: Don't read unconstrained user input into constant size array. Also don't `strcat` unless you can prove that that the target array is sufficiently large. In fact, it may be better to not use `strcat` at all and instead use `std::string` which will make it more difficult for you to make incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Being a newbie, I have trouble taking multi-word input using  string variable. I used ```getline()```, but sometimes it skips a line if there is a space or newline in  console.

Comment: @Miraz read and understand this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)